# EF6 Code First MVC Related Entity null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have these two classes:

```
public class Players
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ResultItems> ResultItems { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItems
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ResultsId { get; set; }
    public Results Results { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Players Player { get; set; }
    public double Cash { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

You'll see here that the database is populating nice as we enter ResultItems:

[image: screenshot]

However, when the page loads, and we loop through the model to create a table of data, the Player entity is null:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone help me understand why it isn't loading? any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: You need to include the Player when making the query. `db.ResultItems.Include("Player").ToList()`

Comment: Thank you. That does the trick. Do you know why this include method has to be ran on the DbContext? In every other situation I have used EF, the master object would just "lazy load" the child object.

Comment: Add a `virtual` to your Player object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `virtual` keyword to your `public Players Player` or you can do `db.ResultItems.Include("Player").ToList()`